# Net Send or MSG? OS= Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file which allows me to communicate with a specific IP adress that will be in a different location. Though, **net send** isn't working, which doesn't surprise me after reading multiple posts by other users. My real question; Net send or MSG.

Here are my results.
My code:

```
msg Pringles /server:GYH4004 /time:300
```

*this is an example, not actual server. I did try it with genuine details...

I get a fancy error message;

```
"'msg' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

Once again my OS is Windows 7, and I have also tried NET SEND and it doesnt work...

Oh, isn't NET SEND been removed since Vista? I am unsure, anyways tried both, no luck.

Appreciate all help!

Pringles

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

`Net Send` and the underlying technology is no longer in Windows (from Vista) for security reasons.

`Msg` send messages to users using Terminal Server, you can use it to send a message to yourself, but not other computers (unless a terminal server).

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any command that I can use that will allow me to send a message to a specific IP?

Comment: Basically a 'net send' replacement